# Creating a wrapper class for a function c++

Tags: c++, functor, std-function

I'm trying to implement a wrapper class for a function so that I can add methods to functions. I've created the class, but the `operator()` only works for some functions. What am I missing?

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename R, typename... Args> class Function;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
class Function<R(Args...)> {
    typedef R return_t;
    typedef R func_t(Args...);
    public:
        std::function<func_t> value;
        Function(func_t f){
            this->value = f;
        };
        return_t operator()(Args... args){
            (std::cout << ... << args) << "\n";
            return this->value((..., args));
        };
};

typedef int func(int, char);
int f(int, char);

int main(){
    func f;
    Function<func> t(f);
    //std::cout << t.value(10, 'c') << std::endl;
    std::cout << t(10, 'c');
}

// Test function
int f(int a, char c){
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: `this->value(args...)`? also you maybe want `std::forward`: `this->value(std::forward<Args>(args)...)` to support rvalue args

Comment: [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)?

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that that worked. I was trying to fold the pack on the comma. Thank you!

Comment: @dewaffled could you post that as an answer?

Comment: nah) someone maybe will write explanation for std::forward, std::invoke and stuff. i am not in the mood atm.